# Non-linear system of modular arithmetic equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there an efficient algorithm to solve the following system of equations?

$\begin{array}{ccccc}
\begin{array}{c}
us_{1}^{2}+vt_{1}^{2}=a_{1}\pmod p\\
us_{2}^{2}+vt_{2}^{2}=a_{2}\pmod p\\
\vdots\\
us_{n}^{2}+vt_{n}^{2}=a_{n}\pmod p
\end{array} &  & \begin{array}{c}
ws_{1}^{2}+xt_{1}^{2}=b_{1}\pmod p\\
ws_{2}^{2}+xt_{2}^{2}=b_{2}\pmod p\\
\vdots\\
ws_{n}^{2}+xt_{n}^{2}=b_{n}\pmod p
\end{array} &  & \begin{array}{c}
ys_{1}+z=c_{1}\pmod p\\
ys_{2}+z=c_{2}\pmod p\\
\vdots\\
ys_{n}+z=c_{n}\pmod p
\end{array}\end{array}$

I read in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Computational_complexity) that such a problem is NP-complete. Wikipedia cited a reference for this. When I looked at the referred book I cannot find the exact problem or the proof.

Intuitively the problem seems hard, if this is true, how to prove that?

- Unknowns: $u,v,w,x,y,z,s_i,t_i$
- $a_i,b_i,c_i,p$ are known. $p$ is an odd prime
- $n\ge6$

Comment: There is not an algorithm, but a method of solving such systems of nonlinear Diophantine equations.  For a large number of equations, the formulas get very cumbersome.  For simple equations - if you want you can look in my blog.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have looked at your blog and the answers you gave to other questions. But, so far I am not able to find a system of equations close enough to the system that I have.
From my perspective I am interested in knowing how hard It will be for a computer to solve if a solution exits. If a formula for a solution can be derived like you said, it will be easy for a computer to solve.

Comment: Not being from a pure mathematical background I am looking for mathematicians like you to show me how to derive the formula for a solution or show that it is really hard but a solution exists.
I see your point about the number of equations and I agree. If you look at the system above we  need at least 18 equations to match the number of unknowns. My intuition is that as the number of equations increase the number of possible solutions decrease and it gets harder to find a solution. If you think there is any merit to this intuition please help me to put this into a formal argument.

Comment: This entry modulo does to solve the equations.  You need to change the very system of equations - for a start.  For example, for linear equations to make a record.  $$ys=cp+z$$  Since the linear equations are solved easily, it is necessary to exclude them from consideration. To Express some through other variables.  That left only the nonlinear equations.  Some of them must be equivalent to each other.  After all transformations - and then you can proceed to the solution of nonlinear equations.